# Как делают такие query?

Tags: веб-программирование

есть сайт *https://www.delivery-club.ru/srv/KFC_msk?vendorCategoriesQuery=-2*

Если мы скроллим вниз url меняется к примеру на *https://www.delivery-club.ru/srv/KFC_msk?vendorCategoriesQuery=300332666*

Это отличное решение ибо позволяет поделиться ссылкой именно на тот пункт меню что требуется. Чем то похож на якорные ссылки но мне кажется здесь другая разработка. Кто может подсказать как такое делается и на чистом ли JS это?

Comment: обычный GET запрос

Comment: Подозреваю что вы имеете в виду History API https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API#%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть предположение, что все продукты грузятся одним запросом. У каждой группы продуктов прописан vendorCategoriesQuery, которой они принадлежат. При заходе без якоря ?vendorCategoriesQuery=-2 вас бросит на начало страницы, при указании якоря скролинг автоматически перебросит вас на нужную категорию продуктов. Скролинг также является умным и если вы перемещаетесь по странице, то он поменяет якорь.

Да, вся эта функциональность прописывается в js.